# card game in c, shuffle linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, shuffle, realloc

I trying to shuffle a linked list in c.
My idea was to move the list into an array of card then to shuffle the array and then to put it all back in the linked list.
when I do build everything is ok but when id use the debugger the program stops and says "triggered a breakpoint" and i didn't to anything different .
Thanks for your help!

here is some of my code

```
typedef struct card
{
  int rank;
  int suit;
}card;

void shuffleDeckPlay(cardList *deck1, int size)
{
card *array = (card*)malloc(sizeof(card));


for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
{
    array[i] = deck1->front->data;
    array = realloc(array, sizeof(card));
    Dequeue(deck1);
}


int i, j;
card temp;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        j = rand() % size;
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Enqueue(array[i], deck1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `array` contains space for one `card`.

Comment: but the realloc should solve it no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array` is only large enough to store one card. Even after you realloc, you are only realloc-ing it to a size of one. Syntactically there is nothing wrong, however during runtime `array[i]` will go out of bounds and the debugger is picking it up. 
The best solution would be to allocate the correct number immediately:

```
card * array = (card*)malloc(numCards*sizeof(card));
```

However if you want to re-allocate in the for loop then your for loop should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    array = (card*)realloc(array, (i+1)*sizeof(card));
    array[i] = deck1->front->data;
    Dequeue(deck1);
}
```